# Comparing elements within list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, zip

I have following list of lists taken from .csv file:

```
[['1002', '27', 'K', '1100004224', '2688.40'],['1002', '50', 'S', '1100004224', 2688.40']]
```

The idea is to iterate through list of lists, compare index 3 ('1100004224') and if they are equal, add index 4 to each other and append into new list.

So result of above (index 1 and 2 disregarded)

```
[['1002', '1100004224', '5376.8']]
```

Edit:

If element is not equal, take following list:

```
[['1002', '27', 'K', '1100004224', '2688.40'],['1002', '50', 'S', '1100004224', 2688.40'],['1002', '50, 'S', '1100004225', '1000']]
```

Result should be:

```
[['1002', '1100004224', '5376.8'],['1002','1100004225','1000']]
```

How could I achieve that? Was looking into zip, trying numerous loops but I am blocked.

Comment: Can you also provide an example when element is not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sum up the values at `l[4]` where key at `l[3]` is equal.
The easiest way to do this is with `defaultdict`

Example code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)

for nested in csv_list:
    d[nested[3]] += nested[4]

new_list = []
for x in d.items():
    new_list.append(list(x))
```

or

```
new_list = [list(x) for x in d.items()]
```

Comment: Getting typeerror in that case: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @underr `d[nested[3]] += float(nested[4])`